# How to inject class instead of service in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

I'd like to achieve the following (without using services.yml - ideally, through some annotation mechanism if the type hinting can't do it):

```
class MyClass {
    private $msgService;

    public function __construct(MessageServiceInterface $msgService) {
        $this->msgService = $msgService;
    }

    public function sendMessage($text) {
        $this->msgService->send($text);
    }
}
```

Basically, I'd like Symfony to be able to tell that MyClass needs to be aware of dependency injection and needs to have an implementation of MessageServiceInterface injected.

I find it quite time consuming to define a service for each class that I need to use (especially if those classes are to be used only within that module, and maybe only even once).

Comment: This is a good question but I think the answer is not to use symfony. This library: https://github.com/rdlowrey/Auryn does what you want and can be installed with composer.

Comment: I read the documentation of Auryn and it really looks good and it seems that it follows the SOLID concept. I also read the documentation of JMSDiExtraBundle suggested by @Matteo - I also like it because it integrates with Symfony but it doesn't adhere to SOLID as Auryn does. Currently I'm checking http://php-di.org/doc/frameworks/symfony2.html (which seems to be a trade-off between these two).

Comment: In general, it is a good topic but; _I find it quite time consuming to define a service for each class_  I'm struggling to believe in that. Service definition per class wouldn't take more than a minute unless you're having your lunch at same time:) For others, it is a copy+paste job with small modifications.

Comment: I agree. But it's not only that, it's also about having to write redundant code/configuration (eg: if the Car class depends on the Engine class, why not just use these two classes instead of defining two additional services?).

Comment: To be honest with you, with IFs and BUTs we would come up with more examples. See, now you're considering to add another bundle to your app for a simple issue (not even an issue but lets say it is for you). I think you'll end up introducing some complexity to your code. Anyway, I like the idea but don't see it as a problem at all. Maybe SensioLabs might introduce a kind of @Annotation with a few params to define services, who knows!

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the service definition and usage with the [JMSDiExtraBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSDiExtraBundle). This bundle provide Advanced Dependency Injection Features for Symfony2. Especially the [Annotation](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSDiExtraBundle/master/annotations) features you can do something like:

**Marks a class as service:**

```
<?php

use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation\Service;

/**
 * @Service("some.service.id", parent="another.service.id", public=false)
 */
class Listener
{
}
```

**This marks the parameters of a method for injection:**

```
<?php

use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation\Inject;
use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation\InjectParams;
use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation\Service;

/**
 * @Service
 */
class Listener
{
    /**
     * @InjectParams({
     *     "em" = @Inject("doctrine.entity_manager")
     * })
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManager $em, Session $session)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

**All without any extra configuration files.**

Hope this help